# search through data in multiple arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uisearchbar, searchbar

im doing a searchbar for my UITableview.

So far its only filtering one array in - (void) searchthroughdata, namely the self.Title. 
But I want it to filter through two arrays - the self.Title and self.Description.

My .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *SearchBar;
```

My .m file:

```
-(void)searchThroughData {

self.results = nil;
NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.SearchBar.text];



self.results = [[self.Title filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];

}



-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

[self searchThroughData];

}


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    return _Title.count;

} else {
    [self searchThroughData];
    return self.results.count;

}

// Return the number of rows in the section.
//return _Title.count;
}
```

How do I make it filter through the NSArray * Description as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to not have multiple arrays. Instead, create a custom object with your

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * Description;
```

(or a dictionary) and have a single array containing those objects (I am assuming something about your data model here...).

Now, when you filter you can just check each item in the predicate with an OR.

Comment: Thanks, I had an idea that it was something along those lines, but I'm a noob. How do i make a single array contain two arrays?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks anyway!!